# KeyError: 'id' in pagination

Tags: planet

I am trying to do the pagination using my own geometry filter. However, I am always getting this: KeyError: 'id'. I can run the example/pagination.py successfully without any error.

Here is my pagination.py:

```
import os
import requests

# our demo filter that filters by geometry, date and cloud cover
from CCIL_filters import geometry_filter, champaign_county

#item_types can be the following:
#"PSScene4Band"
#"PSScene3Band"
#"REScene"
#"REOrthoTile" 
#"Sentinel2L1C"
#"PSOrthoTile"
#"Landsat8L1G"

print(geometry_filter)
# Search API request object
search_endpoint_request = {
    "item_types": ["PSScene4Band"],
    "filter": geometry_filter
}

################################
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (os.environ['PLANET_API_KEY'], '')

# Create a Saved Search
saved_search = \
    session.post(
      'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/searches/',
      json=search_endpoint_request)

# after you create a search, save the id. This is what is needed
# to execute the search.
saved_search_id = saved_search.json()["id"]

# What we want to do with each page of search results
# in this case, just print out each id
def handle_page(page):
    for item in page["features"]:
        print item["id"]

# How to Paginate:
# 1) Request a page of search results
# 2) do something with the page of results
# 3) if there is more data, recurse and call this method on the next page.
def fetch_page(search_url):
    page = session.get(search_url).json()
    handle_page(page)
    next_url = page["_links"].get("_next")
    if next_url:
        fetch_page(next_url)

first_page = \
    ("https://api.planet.com/data/v1/searches/{}" +
    "/results?_page_size={}").format(saved_search_id, 5)

# kick off the pagination
fetch_page(first_page)
```

Could someone give me some help on this?

Comment: This probably means that your geometry filter is malformed. Two things you should do: show the API response since there will be an error message; show what your geometry filter is. Without those, we won't be able to help.

Comment: Thanks @bosth! Here is [my filter](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Jk4snz_txQbDU1VW5TQ1I3bk0) and the [pagination file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Jk4snz_txQQVh4UjZVa2NXNUU). I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The saved search endpoint requires that the posted search filter has a `name`.

If you print the response from the API, you can see this error is being commnicated:

```
print saved_search.json()
{u'field': {u'name': [{u'message': u"'name' is a required property"}]}, u'general': []}
```

You can therefore either add a `name` to your search filter:

```
search_endpoint_request = {
  "item_types": ["PSScene4Band"],
  "filter": geometry_filter,
  "name" : "StackExchange"
}
```

Or you can use the `quick-search` endpoint, which doesn't require a `name`. There's more information in the Planet documentation on [quick-search vs saved-search](https://www.planet.com/docs/reference/data-api/search-api/#quick-search-vs-saved-search).

Comment: Thanks so much for point out this, @bosth! It works fine now.

Comment: No problem Bin! We are happy to help! Cloud you mark the question as solved?